# user_data doesn't create the specified user in Terraform

Tags: terraform, cloud-init

I'm creating a VM instance with RHEL 8.6 using Terraform. I specified the field `user_data` to create a `user` on the machine and also included the `ssh public key` (It seems that by default `cloud-init` is enabled).

However, when I login to the instance I can just login with the `root` user and `ssh key` which I specified initially for the instance using the field `keys = [<ssh-key-refference>]`. I can't login with `ssh demouser@<public-instance-ip> -i ~/.ssh/id-rsa`. I login as root in the instance and it seems that the user is not create as I specified in `user_data`.

I'm not very familiar with `user_data` (which is working similar in every cloud provider) but I tried the following:

```
<terraform-code-for-the-REHL-instance>
user_data: <<EOF
  users:
    - name: demouser
      gecos: Demo User
      sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
      groups: users, admin
      ssh_import_id: None
      lock_passwd: true
      ssh_authorized_keys:
        - ssh-rsa DNMUYRxxxxx
EOF
```

I expected to create the user in the RHEL machine with the specified ssh-key as I declared in the `user_data field`.

I'm not very sure how can I user `user_data` to create a user, with a specific `ssh key` in the instance running REHL. The instance is deployed successfully but the code specified in `user_data` is not creating any user.

Comment: What's exactly is happening with the current code? Any errors?

Comment: No errors. The instance is deployed successfully but the user is not created at all.

Comment: You create a user named `demouser`, but try to ssh in with a user named `testuser`. Why is that? I wouldn't expect that to work.

Comment: That's nothing related with my initial question...

Answer (score 1):

First thing – **very important** – I'd recommend is to check cloud-init logs. They are usually located in the **/var/log/cloud-init.log** file; try to look for any errors or warnings related to your user_data script.

Second, try to force your user_data execution by running `sudo cloud-init single -n user-data`; this will execute your user data and let's you check for any adittional errors

I would also recommend to add these lines to your user data script:

```
runcmd:
 - mkdir -p /home/demouser/.ssh
 - chown -R demouser:demouser /home/demouser
```

This will ensure that the demouser home directory is created and that the SSH directory is set up with the correct ownership.

Comment: Can I add difectly over the code specified in user_data the sudo cloud-init and runcmd? I'd really appreciate and example adding the user-data stuff + runcmd + sudo cloud-init under user_data field.

Comment: Sorry for the late raply, did you manage to solve your issue ?